# How to replace a part of specific string FROM string TO string?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

HI I have a simply question how to replace a part of a string. Lets suppose we a have a string:

```
"This is my string that I need to replace a part FROM to a part TO."
```

and I want to replace all values from **"FROM"** part to **"TO"** part of the string, for example with a "XXX", so string should looks like:

```
"This is my string that I need to replace a part FROM XXX TO."
```

How to do this **SIMPLY** in JS (some commands need to use number/index with can be hard to target with charAt)? Of course string will vary, but some parts will be the same and I need to target them and replace the *'middle ware'* with specific unique string (XXX in this example).

The idea I have is to replace FROM to some specific mark (!), replace TO to some specific mark (@). Replace string from one specific mark (FROM - !) to other specific mark (TO - @) with command that can make use of charAt() that is needed to get index... but it must be a simpler and more elegant way of doing this.

Help the newbie!

Comment: [Regular expressions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Have look at indexof, substr and substring.

Comment: indexOf() and replace() is one option. and regular expression is the other one (that I didn't think of.. :), thx guys, this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 5):

One option could be to use a regex to match in a capturing group `FROM` and capture in a second group any character non greedy `(.*?)` followed by a lookahead `(?=` that asserts what what follows is `TO`

[`(FROM)(.*?)(?= TO)`](https://regex101.com/r/iQ5gyQ/1)

Replace with group 1 followed by a whitespace and XXX

`$1 XXX`

```js
var str = "This is my string that I need to replace a part FROM to a part TO.";
console.log(str.replace(/(FROM)(.*?)(?= TO)/, '$1 XXX'));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can do this.

### A - Using a Regular Expression

```
var str = "This is my string that I need to replace a part FROM to a part TO.";
var res = str.replace(/FROM(.*)TO/, "FROM XXX TO");
```

### B - Finding the Index and Rebuilding the String

```
var posFrom = str.indexOf('FROM');
var posTo = str.indexOf('TO', posFrom);
if (posFrom !== -1 && posTo !== -1) {
    var res = str.substring(0, posFrom) + 'FROM XXX TO' + str.substring(posTo + 2)
}
```

**In both approaches you have to make sure the string doesn't have other words that could be confused with the FROM and TO keywords.**

Answer (score 0):

Use [**String#replace**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with [**RegExp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to mach:

- the beginning `(FROM )`
- the replaceable range as non-greedy `.*?`
- and the end `( TO)`

and use [**special replacement patterns**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) `$1` and `$2`:

```js
const string = "This is my string that I need to replace a part FROM to a part TO.";
const pattern = /(FROM ).*?( TO)/;
const replaced = string.replace(pattern, '$1XXX$2');

console.log(replaced);
```

Or a [**replacement function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in `.replace()`:

```js
const string = "This is my string that I need to replace a part FROM to a part TO.";
const pattern = /(FROM ).*?( TO)/;
const replaced = string.replace(pattern, (fullMatch, fromPart, toPart) => {
  return fromPart + 'XXX' + toPart;
});

console.log(replaced);
```

---

To be able to change the **beginning** and **end** patterns to match (a.k.a. parameterize), construct your `RegExp` with the parameters in a function:

```js
const string = "This is my string that I need to replace a part FROM to a part TO.";

function parameterizedReplace(string, from, to, replacement) {
  return string.replace(new RegExp('(' + from + ' ).*?( ' + to + ')'), '$1' + replacement + '$2');
}

const replaced = parameterizedReplace(string, 'FROM', 'TO', 'XXX');

console.log(replaced);
```

Or using [**template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
const string = 'This is my string that I need to replace a part FROM to a part TO.';

function parameterizedReplace(string, from, to, replacement) {
  return string.replace(new RegExp(`(${from} ).*?( ${to})`), `\$1${replacement}\$2`);
}

const replaced = parameterizedReplace(string, 'FROM', 'TO', 'XXX');

console.log(replaced);
```

[**The pattern on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/rUrv9o/1)

Answer (score -1):

is the replace not enough simple? Be careful in case of multiple instances of the string you are searching all of them will be replaced.

```
var str = "This is my string that I need to replace a part FROM to a part TO.";
var res = str.replace("to a part", "XXX");
```

Further information at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Nope, I guess this has to be dynamic first, and second he needs to get starting char and the ending char and replace what's in the middle.